# Use static function from namespaced as callback in PHP

Tags: php, callback, namespaces

The php function `array_map` allows you to specify a string that refers to a static method like `array_map('MyClass::method', $arr);`. How does this work in combination with the `use` statement?

Suppose I have two PHP files. The first is called b.php:

```
<?php

namespace B;

class A {
  static function bar($i) {
    return $i+1;
  }
}
```

The second file is called foo.php:

```
<?php

require 'b.php';

use B\A;

// this works perfectly fine
print A::bar(5);

$a = array(4, 2);

// this results in an error
$b = array_map('A::bar', $a);

// this works
$c = array_map('B\A::bar', $a);
```

How can I specify the `\B\A::bar` method to `array_map`? Without actually specifying `B`, because that's were I have the `use` statement for.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. BTW, using `['A', 'bar']` as a first param fails as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Relative namespaces and call_user_func()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682356/relative-namespaces-and-call-user-func):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php#110530

Sounds like this is by design.