# php array_map does not find external class

Tags: php, array-map

I have 2 classes `Helper` and `Movies`.

I `Helper` i have a static method `flats()`.

Now i need to use the `flats()` method inside my `Movies` class:

```
array_map(['Helper', 'flats'], $data);
```

But there error come:

```
Warning: array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Helper' not found in bla bla on line xx
```

I have a PSR-4 autoloader, and the other Helper methods works great in the `Movies` class...

Comment: Is the file included in the file which calls it? For example, do you use an autoloader or via `require()` or `include()`

Comment: @RichardBernards The PSR-4 autoloading should handle that

Comment: Are they in the same namespace? Did you `use \Namespace\Of\Helper`?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski whoops... read over the last line...

Comment: yeah there are in the same Namespace.

Comment: Try to use `['\full\name\space\of\Helper', 'flats']`.

Comment: You can use the `__NAMESPACE__` constant also, since they're in the same namespace.

Comment: Ah, here's a good explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682356/relative-namespaces-and-call-user-func